# add style to specific element dynamically

Tags: angular

in my instagram.component.html file i assign `boxPosition` id to my `div`. then i use that in another component which is named sidenav.component.ts. 
sidenav component first run and when i click in one icon in this component then instagram.component execute.

problem is here that at first before instagram component execute i use `boxPosition` element to change right-margin of that but `boxPosition` is null and i see error.

here is my instagram.component.html :

```
<div class="content-container d-rtl">

  <div class="main-rectangular d-rtl" id="boxPosition">

  </div>

</div>
```

here is my instagram.component.ts :

```
export class InstagramComponent implements OnInit {

  @Output('boxPosition') public boxPosition: ElementRef;

  constructor(public appGlobal: AppGlobals) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
}
```

here is my sidnavbar.component.html :

```
<a class="icon-calendar"
   (click)="subSideNav('content-production')"
   routerLinkActive="active" routerLink="./content/production"
   ></a>
```

and here is my sidnavbar.component.ts :

```
subSideNav(id) {
    const navProperty = document.getElementById('subTitleSideNav');
    const navWidth = window.getComputedStyle(navProperty, null).getPropertyValue('width');
    const boxProperty = document.getElementById('boxPosition');


    if (navWidth === '0px') {
      // Open sidenavbar
      document.getElementById('subTitleSideNav').style.width = '140px';
      this.titleID = id;
      console.log(boxProperty);
      document.getElementById('boxPosition').style.marginRight = '240px';

    }
}
```

box property is null so `document.getElementById('boxPosition').style.marginRight` not work.

how can i fix this problem ?

Comment: There are a lot areas that could benefit from improvements in your example. Please show what the app.component.html looks like and there should be a much simpler solution.

Comment: here is my app.component.html 
`<app-header></app-header>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<app-footer></app-footer>`